# UITableViewHeaderFooterView in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to create a custom header section view in a separate .xib using IB

However in IB i cannot find a component UITableViewHeaderFooterView (similar to UITableViewCell) and assign a reuse for it

So how to create in custom header section?

I create a class MySection which inherits from UITableViewHeaderFooterView
Create a .xib, MySection.xib
Register xib for cell reuse

the problem is, how to use the initWitReuseIdentifier....

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's absolutely possible and Apple provides an example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Download the sample code and look at the SectionHeaderView.xib.

The way to do it is to create a xib with a single UIView on it.  Then, set the class type to a class that inherits from UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Once you have a nib with a class that inherits from UITableViewHeaderFooterView, call the following to register the class for reuse as a header or footer:

```
static NSString * const SectionHeaderViewIdentifier = @"SectionHeaderViewIdentifier";

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SectionHeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
```

To put the view into use, implement the table delegate method tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: like so:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSinteger)section {

    SectionHeaderViewClass *sectionHeaderView = (SectionHeaderView *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    // Do stuff...

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: On iOS8 there will be a warning like this:

Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.

To fix, in IB, set the background color of the UIView to "Default".

Comment: In iOS 8.3, You need to also set the UITableView's sectionHeaderHeight property to something, otherwise it defaults to 0 and your delegate method won't be called. (Yeah, this is dumb.)

Comment: Clarifying the OP (because it took me a while): Your XIB should have *one* root-level subview (analogous to a `UITableViewCell`'s content view) and all your other views should be subviews of it. Also in addition to @patr1ck's comment above, it seems in iOS 10.x you must set both `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight` *and* `tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` (even if you override the values for individual sections in your `UITableViewDelegate`.)

Comment: The problem with this is that your subviews of the header/footer view will not end up as subviews of the contentView, where they should be -- instead they will be added directly to the UITableViewHeaderFooterView itself.

Comment: @smileyborg Is there a way at all to add the subviews to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` via Interface Builder?

Answer (score 21):

I have written a [guide](http://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/) (tested on iOS 9), which comprise of 4 steps:

1. Subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`
2. Create Nib with the subclass view, and add 1 container view which contains all other views in the header/footer
3. In `viewDidLoad`, call `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` for the table view
4. Implement `viewForHeaderInSection` and use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` to get back the header/footer

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work with Views in Interface Builder. It doesn't instantiate my UILabel on the view. I tried nesting it in a container view. They are all contained in a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass.

Comment: how to give button action in that UITableViewHeaderFooterView??

Comment: @AndrewKirna Contents on footer view not visible or loading. Only empty grey bar is shown not even background color getting changed. Not getting what is wrong.

Comment: Hi @iPhone7. I only decided to respond because I still have an iPhone 7...jk but that is my phone I commented above because I didn't get it to work either. Since then, I've been designing all of my custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`s in Swift. Then I register the classes with the table and apply them with `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:)`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

While all these answers work, they don't quite address the original question of how to set the `reuseIdentifier` using Interface Builder. It is, indeed, possible with the help of "User Defined Runtime Attributes". You can set the `reuseIdentifier` directly in Interface Builder using an attribute:

[image: Interface Builder user-defined runtime attributes]

Doing this will accomplish exactly the same thing as the native `reuseIdentifier` field in `UITableViewCell` Interface Builder attribute inspector.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug. because technically there should be a field to add identifier as you are able to dequeue `Header View` in `Table View`.

Answer (score 3):

Following workarounds enable me to *drag-assign IB items to code* as variables.  UITableViewHeaderFooterView doesnt allow that out of the box.

1. create a **(New File/CocoaTouchClass)** UITableViewHeaderFooterView
   .h.m.xib normally
2. temporarily ***rename superclass*** from UITableViewHeaderFooterView to UIView. Drag-assign your UI items to code as needed, IB will assign key-value
   correctly, revert back to UITableViewHeaderFooterView when done.
3. in your tableview, use **registerNib:** to register instead of *registerClass:*. prepare the rest of tableview normally (ie:dequeue).

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8, subviews of UITableHeaderFooterView should be in a container view *and* you should not set background on header/footer views. Object Library lacks UITableHeaderFooterView, so I tried the approach of creating an UIView in xib and adding another one into it as Container View. My concern was that there's not content view outlet on UITableHeaderFooterView and I cannot be sure that my content view actually ends up as content view.

This sounds like a hack or API missuse, however I experienced no warnings or problems with this approach:

1. Create a subclass of UITableHeaderFooterView
2. Create an empty xib for it
3. Drag an UITableViewCell from object library
4. Assign the class of your UITableHeaderFooterView to that cell
5. Assign the reuse identifier

I would like to know about any (potential) problems with this approach, please comment.

Comment: I can't assign the class `UITableHeaderFooterView` to a cell. Xcode doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to create a view and assign its class in IB (the reuse identifier doesn't need to be set in interface builder (as by a custom UITableViewCell))

Answer (score -1):

UITableViewHeaderFooterView documentation contains `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` method

But currently (as of Sep 4 '13) Object Library in Interface Builder didn't include a UITableViewHeaderFooterView. 
This makes registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: useless, because there’s no way to configure the view correctly in the nib.
Perhaps it is better to try reusing cell ...

Answer (score -1):

1. create new view in xib
2. Load view from nib and set to view as footerview to tableview

UIView *headerview = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReguistrationHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self.tableview setTableFooterView:headerview];

Answer (score -2):

I always used UITableViewCell as Headers (or Footers) for my tables to be able to  edit them directly in the storyboard.

My workflow :

- I create a MyHeaderTableViewCell class subclassing UITableViewCell and adding all the outlets I need
- I add a UITableViewCell to my table in my storyboard
- I give it a reuse identifier (es: "HeaderCell")
- I dequeue the cell and use its content as my header

The crucial part is returning the contentView of the headerCell (not the headerCell itself) otherwise you'll run into strange behaviors when playing with reloadRowsAt or similar functions (disappearing headers at most).

This is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! MyHeaderTableViewCell

    headerCell.lblTitle.text = "My Title"

    return headerCell.contentView }
```

I never faced issues in doing so (or at least my customers always paid me).

Comment: you write you never encountered any problems, but it looks like a risky approach and misuse of API

Comment: @PeterLapisu thanks for your reply. I agree with you this can be risky and quite a misuse of API but as long as it works without any big drawback I find it to be a good trade-off between clean code and easy of use. So it's just a solution, tough I agree with you, not the cleanest one.

Comment: It's been 5 years now and so far no problem with my method.