# UITableViewHeaderFooterView with IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

After many years of avoiding Interface Builder like the plague I decided to give it a chance. It's not easy.

Take `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for example. Like `UITableViewCell`, it has a `contentView` property. Unlike `UITableViewCell`, it doesn't have a template in the Interface Builder object library.

How are we supposed to use Interface Builder to create a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` with the content inside `contentView`? The fact that `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` exists makes me think this should be possible somehow.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the closest I got to define a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` with IB:

a. Create a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass (`MYTableViewHeaderFooterView`).

b. Create a nib file for the `contentView` only (`MYTableViewHeaderFooterContentView`).

c. Override `initWithReuseIdentifier:` in `MYTableViewHeaderFooterView` to load the view defined in the nib file.

```
 - (instancetype)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray* objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MYTableViewHeaderFooterView"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil];
        UIView *nibView = [objects firstObject];
        UIView *contentView = self.contentView;
        CGSize contentViewSize = contentView.frame.size;
        nibView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentViewSize.width, contentViewSize.height);
        [contentView addSubview:nibView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

d. Register the `MYTableViewHeaderFooterView` class instead of the nib file:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MYTableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Comment: `contentViewSize` is {0,0,0,0}

Comment: This is actually unecessary and apple has some sample code to prove this. Linking this question for newcomers http://stackoverflow.com/a/20073742/1652402

Comment: a blast from the past - you can use contentView.bounds instead of CGRectMake, although @DanielGalasko answer is spot on

Answer (score 25):

I just did this with a footer and a NIB file:

1. Create an empty NIB file with name *CustomFooterView.xib*.
2. Edit the NIB file in the Interface Builder and change the topmost UIView custom class to UITableViewHeaderFooterView.
3. Disable *Auto Layout* in the NIB.
4. Set the background color of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` view to *Default*.
5. Make the view freeform and correct size (for example 320 x 44).
6. In your UITableViewController `viewDidLoad` register the NIB file to be used with a reuse identifier:

   ```
   [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomFooterView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"Footer"];
   ```
7. In your UITableViewController's `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` use the Footer identifier to fetch and return the view:

   ```
   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       if (section == 2)
           return [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"Footer"];

       return nil; 
   }
   ```

Comment: Works great, though I had to do two more things to get this to work: 1. Disable Auto Layout for the NIB. 2. Set the background color of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` view in the NIB to "Default".

Comment: Thanks @Frederik, I updated the answer based on that.

Comment: I think this is the better solution because you can connect outlets in this xib, in the other solution you can't

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution to me.

Comment: This solution worked really well and much cleaner one compared to using tableview cell as header.

Answer (score 14):

Just use the **UITableViewCell** template in IB. Change the class to **UITableViewHeaderFooterView**. Here you have it... with a contentView.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: I don't know if is a "This is the best solution!" but works fine and is easy to do! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I found easier way.

1) Create subclass of UITableViewCell and set your xib file

2) In your header file change superclass from UITableViewCell to UITableViewHeaderFooterView

That's it.

Comment: This does not appear to work with XCode 6.4, at least. When you try to change the class in IB, it doesn't complete (a good sign things are going wrong). If you click away and come back, it reverts to `UITableViewCell`. If you look in the Nib's object list, a `UITableViewCell` is shown. When you do try to load, an assertion fires when the header is dequeued about it being the wrong kind: `'invalid nib registered for identifier (sectionHeader) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView instance'`

Answer (score 6):

This solution works well, especially if you want it to work correctly in relation to Readable Content Guides (introduced in iOS 9). Instead of creating a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, it simply returns a custom UIView (from a XIB) when it is required:

1. Create a new class that subclasses UIView ("AwesomeHeaderView") and create your outlets:

   ```
   class AwesomeHeaderView: UIView {
       @IBOutlet var myCustomLabel: UILabel!
   }
   ```
2. Create a XIB file ("MyNewHeader.xib") with a **UIView** as
   the parent view. Change the parent UIView's class type to your newly created custom class ("AwesomeHeaderView"). As required, add any additional views as it's children and link outlets etc. (NB: To ensure views comply to the new Readable Content Guides I check the boxes "Preserve Superview Margins" and "Follow Readable Width" on all objects).
3. In your UIViewController (or
   UITableViewController) call the following:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       guard let headerView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyNewHeader", owner: nil, options: nil).first as? AwesomeHeaderView else {
           return nil
       }

       // configure header as normal
       headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
       headerView.myCustomLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       headerView.myCustomLabel.text = "Hello"

       return header
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the deprecation warning above and an inability to set background color, etc.. Eventually, I found that according to Apple's documentation,

> You can use [the UITableViewHeaderFooter] class as-is without subclassing in most cases. If you have custom content to display, create the subviews for your content and add them to the view in the contentView property.

Following that suggestion, I took these steps:

1. I created a xib with a view that extends only UIView--not UITableViewHeaderFooter.
2. In viewDidLoad I registered the built-in UITableViewHeaderFooter class

   tableView.registerClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader")
3. In the viewForHeaderInSection delegate of my UITableViewController, I dequeued the header view by that identifier and checked to see if the header view already contained a subview. If not, I load my xib and add it. Then I set my text as needed.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let header = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("sectionHeader")!

   if header.contentView.subviews.count == 0 { header.contentView.addSubview(loadMyNib()) }

   let myView = header.contentView.subviews[0] as! MyView
   myView.label.text = "..."
   ```

This seems to work, leverages reuse, and does not produce any warnings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewHeaderFooterView/prepareForReuse

Answer (score 1):

Following workarounds enable me to *drag-assign IB items to code* as variables.  UITableViewHeaderFooterView doesnt allow that out of the box.

1. create a **(New File/CocoaTouchClass)** UITableViewHeaderFooterView
   .h.m.xib normally
2. temporarily ***rename superclass*** from UITableViewHeaderFooterView to UIView. Drag-assign your UI items to code as needed, IB will assign key-value
   correctly, revert back to UITableViewHeaderFooterView when done.
3. in your tableview, use **registerNib:** to register instead of *registerClass:*. prepare the rest of tableview normally (ie:dequeue).

Answer (score 0):

An awful hack I figured out is to create a IBOutlet contentView ih your headerFooter class and hook it up to the your "content view" in the xib (Have your xib laid out like a tableViewCell, View->contentView->mystuff).

You'll get warnings, ok ready for the hack...

Delete the IBOutlet and it will all work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found:

1. Create your HeaderFooterView(.h/.m), such as `header`
2. Create a xib(view), name the same
3. Make the root view class as your class(`header`)
4. [**important**] Connect all outlets to the root view, not the `File's Owner`

Last, register your nib to table(All done).