# Custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView with XIB and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am getting this error from my custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. WYBDetailHeaderView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'`

I have subclassed `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and created a XIB file which I load using `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` on my `UITableView`.

As there is no `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in IB, I have followed the advice in other posts and just used `UIView` ([UITableViewHeaderFooterView in InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651880/uitableviewheaderfooterview-in-interfacebuilder); [UITableViewHeaderFooterView with IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162246/uitableviewheaderfooterview-with-ib)).

My custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` uses AutoLayout and includes two multi-line `UILabel`'s, and I assume the problem is related to the fact that these subviews are on the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` itself and not `.contentView`. However I do not know how to do that using IB.

This is my `layoutSubviews` implementation (I've tried a few combinations without success). I even get the error when I remove this function altogether:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Commented out because of infinite loop.
    //  If this was a custom UITableViewCell I would call these methods on self.contentView
    //[self setNeedsLayout];
    //[self layoutIfNeeded];

    self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.titleLabel.frame);
    self.subtitleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.subtitleLabel.frame);
}
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: From the top of my head : did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` on the headerView ?

Comment: Thanks @Nerkatel I tried that in `initWithCoder:` but get the same error.

Comment: What I actually meant is : I got the same error when instantiating programmatically from a `UINib`, then from setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. Leaving it to `YES` is the way to go. But from your comment I guess you didn't have it set to `NO`. You do have your headerView set entirely in the xib file and don't use `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = …`, right?

Comment: @Nerkatel thanks for the continued help. I have tried `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` both ways. Incidentally I am using the `UINib` for custom section headers rather than as `tableHeaderView`. Having registered the NIB I am using `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:` from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: The only way I seem to be able to reproduce, using what you gave us, is when the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass implements `layoutSubviews` without calling super `layoutSubviews`. Additional info might be needed : Care to list the status of each of your xib and views ? Do both the tableView and customTableSectionHeaderView use autolayout in their xib ? Do all of your views ave constraints set to them ? Care to post all code relevant to WYBDetailHeaderView ? Finally, you may want to try to reproduce this issue in a minimalist project using your xibs, this may help isolate the problem.

Comment: @Nerkatel you've been really helpful. I tried a minimalist project as you suggested and my existing code worked straightaway. Now it works in my original project. I didn't change anything so it seems I needed to do a clean and rebuild. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method :

`-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Then, load xib file in it.